# Getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined but cannot figure out why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I'm currently following a youtube app course on the FCC channel. All is well and I'm close to finishing it, but I've had a problem since halfway through working on the client-side of the application. I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined` and it highlights "credentials" in the following code:

```js
render () {
  const {
    classes,
    user: {
      credentials: { handle, createdAt, imageUrl, bio, website, location },
      loading,
      authenticated,
    },
  } = this.props;
```

I have no idea why and I've tried several solutions I found by other users but to no avail. Here is a link to my work on github "https://github.com/HelmutKaltsburg/socialize-client" and there error is in the following js file "https://github.com/HelmutKaltsburg/socialize-client/blob/master/src/components/profile/Profile.js"

EDIT: I checked my redux state, after the user logs in "authenticated" becomes true but the "credentials" don't, and after the error message has displayed the credentials all load and thus I'm left at the error message and have to manually go to localhost:3000/home

Comment: Maybe it's because the user object from props does not contain `credentials` key.

Comment: Upon manually going to localhost:3000/home it loads as it should, the error only happens on login which should redirect to /home anyway.